# What is major process of delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates

what is main reason for introducing delegates and also it is solution for which type problems.i like to  know that problem.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can *mostly* think of delegates as being like interfaces with a single method. So in places where a language without delegates (such as Java) would use an interface, it makes sense to have a delegate.

Delegates have these benefits over interfaces:

- The implementation can be private, whereas methods implementing interfaces have to be public in Java. (C# has explicit interface implementation as well.)
- You can implement multiple delegates in a single class, or even the same delegate type multiple times
- The framework and language have additional support for delegates:

  - Combining them together (and removing them)
  - A pub/sub framework (events)
  - Background invocation using the thread pool (BeginInvoke etc)
  - Lambda expressions and anonymous methods make them easy to create "inline"
  - Expression trees, representing the logic of an expression in data rather than IL

Delegates are typically used for:

- Event handling, e.g. in GUIs
- Providing "small" pieces of behaviour, e.g. the filters and projections in LINQ
- Callbacks for asynchronous programming

Think of them as a way of encapsulating a single piece of behaviour, and see where that leads you.